# Integrate SSO login for the custom python application

Tags: python, saml-2.0

I'm a beginner for coding and modifying the existing codes etc.
I want to implement this sso login https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml for the custom python application.
Since I'm a beginner I don't understand how to start with. Where do i need to modify, understand code flow,  and how to begin..
Kindly help with some of your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

There are very good instructions with that kit.

What IDP are you using?

Essentially, get the Python metadata and use it to configure the IDP.

Get the IDP metadata and use it to configure Python.

There's a tutorial [here](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/python).

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable comment.. We are using google IdP. I gone through that tutorial. If i want to integrate https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml with https://github.com/linkedin/oncall, is it possible? Could you please guide me to achieve it ?